# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::mysqli_fetch_array() in

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I try to get the 5 most-watched Movies from my database and echo the output. Below are some of the related lines:

```
$sqlGetTop5 = "SELECT TVSeries_ID,COUNT(TVSeries_ID) AS Frequency FROM TVSeries_Watched GROUP BY TVSeries_ID ORDER BY Frequency DESC LIMIT 5";
$ResultGetTop5 = $DBConnect->query($sqlGetTop5);
            
while($row = $ResultGetTop5->mysqli_fetch_array()){
                
      echo $row['Frequency'];
                
}
```

But when I execute the query, "*Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::mysqli_fetch_array() in...*" has occurred. I have no idea how to solve it. What is the problem and how to solve this issue?

Comment: The `query` method returns `FALSE` on fail. It looks like the SQL is not valid. Can you check your `GROUP BY`

Comment: How is `$DBConnect` defined? Most probably the db connection failed.

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_array` is not a method of `mysqli_result`. Check the manual for the right syntax

Comment: If you are only starting to learn PHP then you should learn PDO instead of mysqli. PDO is much easier and more suitable for beginners. Start here https://phpdelusions.net/pdo & https://websitebeaver.com/php-pdo-prepared-statements-to-prevent-sql-injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the (very helpful) [PHP docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php):

`$DBConnect->query($sqlGetTop5)` returns `false` if the query failed.
This means something is wrong with your query. Though I am no SQL expert `GROUD BY ORDER BY` looks a little weird to me.